# IF record DOES NOT EXIST in Table1, UPDATE Table2, ELSE IF record EXISTS UPDATE Table2 with column from Table1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I am going to do the following in a `STORED PROCEDURE`in `T-SQL`.

Table1 consists of some rows that are arbitrary. Table2 consists of more rows than Table1, but those that exists are the same, except for one column which holds a date.

If a row in Table1 exists in Table2, I want to update the date column for Table2.
If a row in Table2 does not exist in Table1, I want to update the date column for Table2 as well.

I cannot for the life of me figure out the syntax to make this happen, as this stored procedure will not take in any parameters or output any parameters.

Comment: If record not exists in table 1 then what value u will go and update in table2

Comment: @Pradeep The same as if it exists, only I will set the date to today's date instead of the date returned from Table1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table1
   set table1.date = insull(table2.date, getdate()) 
  from table1 
  left jion table2 
    on table2.ID = table1.ID
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! :)

Do you know of anything I should read in order to brush up on SQL syntax? I find it unnecessary hard, I just cannot wrap my head around it at all.

Again, thank you!

Comment: I learned back when it was Sql Server 6.5 so no.  Since then I have us the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should get diff of tables. Check following:

```
set nocount on
declare @t1 table (id int, datecolumn datetime)
declare @t2 table (id int, datecolumn datetime, fk_on_t1 int)

declare @diff table(t1_id int, t2_id int)

insert into @diff(t1_id,t2_id)
select
t1.Id
,t2.ID 
from @t1 t1 
full join @t2 t2 on t1.id = t2.fk_on_t1
```

Now you can understand what rows exists one or another tables. You can use query like this to update your date column for your case:

```
update t2
set datecolumn = getdate()
from @t2 t2
inner join @diff d on d.t2_id = t2.ID
where d.t2_id is not null
```

Commonly, you can make just one query instead of mine two. Check this:

```
update t1
set datecolumn = getdate()
from @t1 t1
full join @t2 t2 on t1.id = t2.fk_on_t1
where t2.ID is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
UPDATE A 
SET    A.datecol= CASE 
                  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                               FROM   Table1 B 
                               WHERE  B.cola = A.cola) THEN c.Datecol
                  ELSE getdate() 
                END 
FROM   Table2 A 
       JOIN Table1 C 
         ON a.cola = c.cola
```